# How to improve performance of query execution

Tags: join, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

Following query is taking time(2.3s) to execute.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(c2.id) AS c2__0 
FROM countryMaster c, stateMaster s, cityMaster c2, categoryMaster c3, categoryMaster c4, product p 
INNER JOIN user u ON ((u.id = p.user_id AND u.is_active = 1))
WHERE (p.category_id = c4.id 
AND c2.id = p.x_area_id
AND c2.parent_id = s.id 
AND s.parent_id = c.id AND c3.id IN ('1271')
AND c4.rgt = (c4.lft + 1)
AND c4.lft BETWEEN c3.lft AND c3.rgt AND p.status = 1)
GROUP BY c.id;


Explain:    
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c3
         type: const
possible_keys: PRIMARY,lft_rgt_inx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: p
         type: ALL
possible_keys: INX_cmp_sx,status
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 29958
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c4
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,lft_rgt_inx
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: yozoa1_live.p.category_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: u
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,is_active
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: yozoa1_live.p.user_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c2
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,parent_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: yozoa1_live.p.x_area_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,parent_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: yozoa1_live.c2.parent_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: yozoa1_live.s.parent_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: 


Show create table -     
CREATE TABLE `categoryMaster` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `is_featured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_map` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_price_required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort_order` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `lft_rgt_inx` (`lft`,`rgt`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `product_count` (`product_count`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM


CREATE TABLE `productMaster` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `sub_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sub_description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_new` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `currency_main` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'MNT',
  `price_original` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price_global` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `attribute_value_ids` text,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '7',
  `rental_duration` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `buy_online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `internal` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_status` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
  `delivery_type` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
  `phone_cell` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_home` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x_area_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x_area_location_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sublocality_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_posting_price` double NOT NULL,
  `is_paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `product_posting_currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `map_lat` double NOT NULL,
  `map_lng` double NOT NULL,
  `product_company_contact_info_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `backup_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
  `is_scraped` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sources_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `product_source_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_cmp_icsu` (`id`,`category_id`,`status`,`user_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `state_id` (`state_id`),
  KEY `INX_cmp_sx` (`status`,`x_area_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `attribute_value_ids` (`attribute_value_ids`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM


CREATE TABLE `cityMaster` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `map_lat` double NOT NULL,
  `map_lng` double NOT NULL,
  `has_sublocality` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM


CREATE TABLE `stateMaster` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `map_lat` double NOT NULL,
  `map_lng` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM


CREATE TABLE `countryMaster` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `map_lat` double NOT NULL,
  `map_lng` double NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Please suggest me how can I reduce execution time of this query with indexing.
And also let me know why query explain shows null in ref column?
Also let me know steps to optimize query?

Comment: user table is missing?

Comment: Try adding an index on x_area_id in productMaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so looking over this, I think what you need to do is add an index on x_area_id to productMaster, or perhaps a multi-column index. Here's why:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(c2.id) AS c2__0 
FROM countryMaster c, stateMaster s, cityMaster c2, categoryMaster c3, categoryMaster c4, product p 
INNER JOIN user u ON ((u.id = p.user_id AND u.is_active = 1))
WHERE (p.category_id = c4.id 
AND c2.id = p.x_area_id
AND c2.parent_id = s.id 
AND s.parent_id = c.id AND c3.id IN ('1271')
AND c4.rgt = (c4.lft + 1)
AND c4.lft BETWEEN c3.lft AND c3.rgt AND p.status = 1)
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Note the join condition here:

```
AND c2.id = p.x_area_id
```

And also note in that in the product master table, you have indices on

```
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_cmp_icsu` (`id`,`category_id`,`status`,`user_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `state_id` (`state_id`),
  KEY `INX_cmp_sx` (`status`,`x_area_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `attribute_value_ids` (`attribute_value_ids`)
```

Notably, not x_area_id.

The fact that SQL is mentioning possible keys has to do with this part of your SQL statement:

```
AND c4.lft BETWEEN c3.lft AND c3.rgt AND p.status = 1)
```

In essence, SQL is noticing that it might be able to use the fact that status = 1 to leverage the INX_cmp_sx key. It's been a while since I've done a lot of work in MyISAM, but I suspect that's because it's elected to use the index on p.user_id for the join against the user table and the query optimizer decided against performing an index merge.

If it were me, I'd try two things. First, I'd try simply adding a key on x_area_id and seeing if that improves the performance (definitely run explain on that... obviously). If it does not, then I'd think about adding a compound index on (user_id, status, and x_area_id). Exactly which column should be first in the index it's totally clear to me from looking at this... I would guess status, but you'd need to test that.

Also, I'd like to point out that the status index you have on the productMaster table

```
  KEY `INX_cmp_sx` (`status`,`x_area_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
```

is redundant, because of INX_cmp_sx key. So you may want to try replacing the status index with something like (user_id, status, and x_area_id) or (user_id, x_area_id, status) or something along those lines.

Technically you could just index them all separately, but that sometimes has a tendency to backfire (eg http://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/)

Bottom line: get rid of the status key and replace it with some variations of (user_id, status, and x_area_id). Even try getting rid of INX_cmp_sx and replacing it with (status, user_id, x_area_id) or (status,x_area_id, user_id).  The output of your explain is basically telling you that MySQL can't find a way to pull out a cross section of the data that correspond to the combination of (status, user_id, x_area_id) that would be any more efficient that simply reading the entire productMaster table. Play around with the indices on those columns and you should find something that works much better. And, again, there is a chance that simply adding x_area_id will straight this all out. I'd definitely give that a shot first.